# Video Editor Preview shows content of a Videofile I already removed from the timeline

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]

As you can see here, Blender is showing the OBS screen and the game recording after that from the video file I already removed from the timeline, when I tried to render it to a video just to find out what happens it still shows the recording... I removed the video, I don't want blender to render or show it in the preview, this honestly looks like a strange bug to me, or maybe I am missing a setting. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could be VFR problems, which should have been solved in latest versions of Blender. What version are you on?

Comment: @tintwotin the latest steam version: 3.4